# CodeIgniter run library before database settings

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I test my Codeigniter site on localhost then update it on a server. Switching between them involves a lot of adjustment-related problems.

So I want to config it by only one constant: `MYCUSTOM_SERVER_LOCATION`

Then my database connection and password is configured according to location of my server(localhost or myhost). The only problem is that database.php is run before `mysettings` library. Even doing settings in a config file instead of a library has the same result.

**[UPDATED]**

---

application/config/autoload.php:

```
...
$autoload['libraries'] = array('mysettings','database','session');
...
```

---

application/libraries/mysettings.php:

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

define("MYCUSTOM_SERVER_LOCATION", "localhost");

class mysettings {

//////////////////////////////////////////////////
// option: localhost
// option: 000webhost
//$config["mycustom_server"]="localhost";

}
```

---

application/config/database.php

```
if(MYCUSTOM_SERVER_LOCATION=="localhost")
{
    $db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
    $db['default']['username'] = '...';
    $db['default']['password'] = '...';
    $db['default']['database'] = '...';
}
else if(MYCUSTOM_SERVER_LOCATION=="myserver")
{
    $db['default']['hostname'] = '...';
    $db['default']['username'] = '...';
    $db['default']['password'] = '...';
    $db['default']['database'] = '...';
}
else
{
    echo "Unknown server.";
}
```

---

output result:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Use of undefined constant MYCUSTOM_SERVER_LOCATION - assumed 'MYCUSTOM_SERVER_LOCATION'
Filename: config/database.php
Line Number: 51


A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Use of undefined constant MYCUSTOM_SERVER_LOCATION - assumed 'MYCUSTOM_SERVER_LOCATION'
Filename: config/database.php
Line Number: 58


Unknown server.
```

Comment: have you tried using hooks? i think this is what you need for you're problem http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/hooks.html

Comment: updated previous error due to using $ before a constant. @tomexsans I don't know about hooks. do they help in this case? (without touching system folder)

Comment: @germar a simple switch would do the trick. The activerecord variable is where CI know what database settings to load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `$active_group` variable in `application/config/database.php`

**Example Usage:**

```
/* 
 The $active_group variable lets you choose which connection group to
 make active.  By default there is only one group (the 'default' group).
*/

$active_group = "development";

$db['development']['hostname'] = "localhost";
$db['development']['username'] = "us";
$db['development']['password'] = "";
$db['development']['database'] = "db1";
```